# Unknown male character in Suspiria?

Tags: plot-explanation, suspiria-1977

In [*Suspiria*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076786/), we see a male arm several times throughout the film. It smashes through a window and pins Pam's face against the glass, then is seen stabbing her.

Later, the same arm is seen stabbing Sara as she struggles helplessly in the barbed wire.

Does this male arm belong to an actual character or is it something conjured up by the witches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen "Suspiria" many times and I would say it is a monster called up by the main witch to kill her enemies. The arm is hairy and has long nails and seems inhuman. Also the arm comes through a window that's very high up, and it seems no human could be up that high without supernatural abilities.

Here is the 1st murder in the movie, you can see some otherworldly eyes appear out of the darkness at 1:53 of this scene. You can see the hairy arm crash through the window at 2:03.

WARNING!! VERY GRAPHIC!!

Comment: Also, I couldn't find the interview, it was in Fangoria magazine or maybe Video Watchdog, but I remember Argento saying that the arm stabbing the girl was HIS arm!